# Is this setup possible in any way? (VLANs with MF286 ISP LTE Modem/Router and managed switch)

Tags: networking, router, routing, modem

[Network Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf7tl.jpg)

I would like to change my network as shown in the picture and i am not sure if it will work. Thought i would ask some experts befor i break my network...

The provided LTE Modem has close to none options available, no bridge mode, no static routes. All i can change is the IP and Subnetmask.

VLAN 10 is the Modem/Internet Access

VLAN 20 all normal Devices (Router ofc in AP Mode)

VLAN 30 IoT and mainly IP-Cams (Router ofc in AP Mode)

I would like access from 20 to 10 and 30. The outgoing connection from 30 to 10 should be possible, but most of the time it would be disabled, only active for remote access of the cams when noone is home. If possible open only for smtp.gmail.com

It's the first time for me dealing with VLANs so it's likely i don't get everything. In the past i slammed everything together into one network and it worked "ok", but with IPCs i would like to take them offline if not needed. As well the traffic was getting to much for one wifi AP.

The problem i saw is that i can't give my modem/router combo static routes, so even if i combine VLAN 10 and 20 to one VLAN, i have no option to tell it where to route requests from VLAN 30 right?
Or is dynamic routing a thing?... o_O

Would this be solveable if i connect a second port, mapped to VLAN 30 on the switch, to the modem? I read something like this somewhere, but since the modem only can have one IP i don't think it would work?...

Most sollutions would need another router between switch and modem, but this would lead to double NAT, which is bad right?

Maybe someone can tell me the important steps to success, like i said, first time, so please talk no me like i don't know what i am doing ^_^

If there is any other (better) solution i would appreciate any advice!

Thank you all ^_^

Comment: Are the Archers in "router" mode, or are they in "bridge/AP" mode? Normally VLANs end at router boundary, so if the Archers act as routers (e.g. if 10.0.20.0/24 is Archer#1's LAN), then their networks are _not_ VLAN 20 and VLAN 30 anymore; the VLANs defined on the switch would only go as far as the routers' "WAN" interfaces... and in fact the VLANs would be useless, but static routes would be necessary. On the other hand, if each Archer is in bridge/AP mode and the ZTE is supposed to be the router for all VLANs, then it's a different situation and I'd be writing a different answer.

Comment: Forgot to define it in the overview, added it to the text. The 2 Archers are in AP mode ofc. I didn't even think router-mode would be possible since i never had used a managed switch befor, but even if it would work, this would also induce the double NAT problem i guess. So yes, AP node for both Archers.

Comment: Does the ZTE router at least allow you to configure a different subnet mask (i.e. make the LAN be a larger /22 instead of the usual /24)? Proxy-ARP could still help in a situation where routes are impossible to define, by making the router _think_ that hosts on distant subnets are local.

Comment: yes, it does. i can set the IP, subnet mask and disable DHCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router (i.e. the ZTE) must itself support VLANs. More specifically, it needs to support:

1. Multiple LANs in general. A router will just naturally forward packets between LANs (subject to firewall rules), the problem is that many home gateways don't *allow* you to define more than one network in the first place.

   If your router doesn't support this, not much you can do with it – you'll need a second router. (See the end of the post for avoiding double NAT.)
2. 802.1Q tagging, which lets it run multiple VLANs over a single Ethernet connection to your switch (that's the "tagged" or "trunk" option in your Netgear).

   If 802.1Q support is missing but the router at least allows separating its "LAN" Ethernet ports to different LANs, you can work around it by using several physical connections, just like you described.

> The problem i saw is that i can't give my modem/router combo static routes, so even if i combine VLAN 10 and 20 to one VLAN, i have no option to tell it where to route requests from VLAN 30 right?

If the router supported VLANs (or even separate port-based LANs) in general, then it wouldn't actually need any static routes as it would automatically have *local subnet* routes for each network that it's participating in. (Also called "link routes" or "direct routes" or "connected routes".)

Every device (router or not) automatically knows a direct route to its own subnet (that's what the "subnet mask" is actually used for), and a router that's directly connected to multiple LANs will just have direct routes for each of them.

So if you only have *one* router, then a more important question is not whether it supports static routes (it doesn't need any) but whether it supports managing multiple networks directly.

> Or is dynamic routing a thing?... o_O

Dynamic routing is indeed a thing – protocols such as OSPF, Babel, BGP, or IS-IS are commonly used inside larger networks to exchange routes between routers. (OpenWRT and RouterOS could support OSPF, as could a Pi running Bird2 or FRR. Very small networks may also use RIP; occasionally even cheap home gateways have RIP support for some reason.)

The IETF "Homenet" project aims to bring automatic OSPF support to home gateways and to end "double NAT" someday.

> Would this be solveable if i connect a second port, mapped to VLAN 30 on the switch, to the modem?

This trick only works if the router supports multiple networks *in general,* but only lacks support for 802.1Q tagged VLANs. I have seen some home wireless routers/modems like that – they don't have 802.1Q support but still have "port-based VLAN" support (where individual LAN ports can be removed from the main LAN and assigned to a different VLAN), so it's possible to use multiple physical connections instead, one per VLAN.

But if the router only supports one WAN and one LAN, period, then there's nothing you can do with it here.

---

If you have two routers chained before the Netgear switch (i.e. ZTE router → a new route with VLAN support → switch), there is still a way to avoid double-NAT in this situation: First make the ZTE router's LAN subnet large enough that it *overlaps* all of your VLAN subnets (by adjusting the subnet mask). It will think all hosts in all VLANs are local and will make direct ARP queries for them, so use the new router's "proxy ARP" feature to make it answer ARP on behalf of all those hosts (and of course disable NAT on the new router while you're at it).

The end effect will be *very* similar to creating routes on the ZTE, except instead of one static routing-table entry it'll have a whole lot of dynamic ARP-cache entries.

(Many home routers don't support proxy-ARP either, but Archer firmware apparently does. It's a simple feature that's already part of the Linux kernel that many of those firmwares are using, although very rarely needed so it's usually not exposed in the GUI.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed Info! Any advice on a not too expensive routermodel to chain behind the ZTE? And i am right to asume i will still need the managed switch in between right? So ZTE<->Route<->Switch<=>Archers
Enabling/Disabling of the VLAN 10<->VLAN 30 connection would be manged by the switch right?
I kind of hoped a managed switch would be able to mange the static routing as well, but i guess that another price-class if at all?
Thanks again, you are a great help!

Comment: Personally I'd go for Mikrotik products because they have _very_ capable firmware (not to mention actually getting firmware updates...) Out-of-the-box I don't really know what other products can do, e.g. I've _heard_ that TP-Link Archer can do a lot but have not used it myself. Converting routers to OpenWRT can often unearth hidden capabilities like full or partial VLAN support, though often at the cost of non-ideal performance.

Comment: Packet forwarding between VLANs is always done by a router (which just sees them as physically separate networks). Switches, managed or not, don't really deal with routing in general. In your setup, packets from VLAN 30 would go to the router (on Netgear "trunk" port), it would check its firewall rules, and if the firewall allows it then the router forwards packets back to VLAN 10. (Same happens even without VLANs, when you configure ports as separate network interfaces, i.e. the way larger dedicated routers work.)

Comment: (There's indeed a more expensive class called "L3 switches", but the "L3" part in those is just the same routing that a router does, you'd still have multiple subnets like with a router, and you'd still need to tell the ZTE _where_ those subnets need to be routed to – it's inability to do this last part that creates the need for double NAT.)

Comment: Ok, got it. I guess i won't touch OpenWRT for now, little steps and so.
Last question i have for now, should i connect the router to the switch on one connection or one for each VLAN port on the switch? It would be one if i use a "trunk" port right? Otherwise each their own?
I also thought i would have to tell the switch which VLAN is allowed to talk to each other, but you are writing that this will be managed by the firewall of the router in front of the switch. I guess the configexample i got this idea from was from a L3 switch then?
Thanks again!

Comment: https://kb.netgear.com/30818/How-to-configure-routing-VLANs-on-a-NETGEAR-managed-switch-with-shared-internet-access

Comment: Yeah, the example looks a lot like enabling routing in an L3 switch (it talks about IP routing, has tabs for RIP and OSPF, etc). Looks like it has hardware-based ACLs, which could be processed faster than a cheap router's CPU-based firewall rules (although one downside is that they're usually stateless and can't be used for "one way" communications – e.g. allowing an NVR to respond to a PC's connection, but not to initiate its own connections – which firewall rules can do.) Plain L2-only switches sometimes also have ACLs to be used _within_ a VLAN, but those aren't really useful here.

Comment: Whether to use a single trunk (with tagged VLANs) or whether to use individual connections somewhat depends on what kind of router you end up with. I think a trunk connection for everything is more common overall, though with the downside that all VLANs share the available throughput of a single gigabit port. (Commonly called "router on a stick".) On the other hand, if you had the Archers in "router" mode, for example, they could be wired directly to the "main" router's individual interfaces without even involving VLANs (but requiring more routing instead).

Comment: I am looking for another router atm, the Archer has no option for proxy ARP in the manual, but an option do disable the routers NAT, would that work in your opinion? I just thing 3 times the same router is easier for me than bringing another brand and modell into the mix. And once more, thank you ^_^

Comment: Disabling NAT isn't enough as the ZTE router won't know where to send packets back to those subnets when they're no longer hidden by NAT; this problem is exactly what makes people *enable* double NAT. Generally I don't think it's a problem to have 2 different devices, when they serve 2 different purposes.